# Is there a way to get the metadata of a picture in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, location, metadata, jpeg

I am building an app where the users can upload the pictures from there phones. I would like to extract from the user's picture the metadata that shows the location that the picture was taken. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [exif](https://pub.dev/packages/exif) package

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/jpg/2.jpg');
var list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

final data = await readExifFromBytes(list);

if (data.isEmpty) {
  print("No EXIF information found");
  return;
}

if (data.containsKey('JPEGThumbnail')) {
  print('File has JPEG thumbnail');
  data.remove('JPEGThumbnail');
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `exif` package does not support `.png` files for some reason - see [issue](https://github.com/bigflood/dartexif/issues/15). Another package https://pub.dev/packages/metadata does support `.png` and `.jpeg` but doesn't currently support null safety yet so cannot be used in Flutter 3 projects, unfortunately.